# How I can associate my user id in angular-file-upload with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, file-upload

I am using angular-file-upload ( https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload ) with Rails .. I want to associate the user id for foreign key when I upload the photo.

this will the structure for the model

User has many photos

sample code:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/photos/'
});
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple  /><br/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload


<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" ng-click="uploader.uploadAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload all
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do something like this:
`assuming the user's id is in $scope.user.id`

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/photos/',
    formData: [
      user_id: $scope.user.id
    ]
});
```

This adds a new parameter with the request that has the user's id
then in the rails controller you can do something like:

```
@photo = Photo.create(photo: params[:file],user_id: params[:user_id])
```

Comment: @WesFoster I edited my answer, sorry for the lack of explanation.